# How to query by value or if value is null JpaRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

There is an entity with column **A** and column **B**, 
I have JpaRepository with method that works fine:

```
@Repository 
    public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Entity, UUID> {
    List<Entity> findAllByAAndB(String a, String b);
}
```

But also I need to fetch all rows where **b** is equal and **a** is null

```
List<Entity> findAllByAAndBOrAIsNullAndB(String a, String b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the second method is not needed, the first one works fine:

```
Repo.findAllByAAndB(null, SerachedValueForB)
```

Depending on the found value, we pass any corresponding parameter

```
Repo.findAllByAAndB("0", SerachedValueForB)
Repo.findAllByAAndB(SerachedValueForA, SerachedValueForB)
```

In heart, the signatures of the searching methods are the same (returned and passed parameteres), but this is wrong.

```
List<Entity> findAllByAAndB(String a, String b);
List<Entity> findAllByAAndBOrAIsNullAndB(String a, String b);
```

Although the method's names are different its purpose and the essence are the same.

Another special case is if you need, for example, to select a parameter by the maximum value, in such cases you need a special method.